# Cards with instalments/installments?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to understand if the word 'instalments' has double 'l'. I googled it, but I did not manage to find an answer.

Comment: instalment British English, installment American English

Comment: Enrolment (British) enrollment (American) BUT traveler (American) traveller (British). Devilment (both).

Answer (score 1):

According to Oxford Living Dictionary 
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/:

British English - 
***INSTALMENT***

American English -
***INSTALLMENT***

According to
Cambridge Dictionary:

***instalment***
 noun [ C ]

mainly UK

US usually

***installment***